# Timeout and DB Error while deleting multiple items and unable to un localize item

Tags: 2013, content-manager, upgrade, sites-9.5

We recently worked on upgarding Content manager DBfrom Tridion 2013 SP1 to Sites 9.5 and we found following Error

A database error occurred while executing Stored Procedure EDA_ITEMS_DELETE_82.

Answer (score 2):

We applied hotfix CM_9.5.0.26550 to fix the issue- Create Index for ITEMS (BLOB_ID)

> IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT NAME FROM sysindexes WHERE NAME = 'IX_ITEMS_061')
> BEGIN
> CREATE INDEX IX_ITEMS_061 ON ITEMS(BLOB_ID)
> WITH FILLFACTOR = 80
> END
> GO